# Order of entries in a dictionary composed by comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

I read that Python's `dict`s are ordered by insertion order. However, the following example code prints `dict` with seemingly random orders varying from run to run:

```py
DICT = {"1D Hist": 1, "1D Plot": 2}
print(DICT)

dict = {entry for entry in DICT}
print(dict)
```

Why is that? Is that intended?

```
C:\Code>python bug.py
{'1D Hist': 1, '1D Plot': 2}
{'1D Plot', '1D Hist'}

C:\Code>python bug.py
{'1D Hist': 1, '1D Plot': 2}
{'1D Hist', '1D Plot'}
```

I am using Pyton 3.11.4.

Comment: That's a set comprehension, not a dictionary comprehension. Sets are unordered.

Comment: Your `dict` is not a dict, it's a set.

Comment: BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is, in fact, intentional behavior.  Python uses the value of `PYTHONHASHSEED` to determine the hash value of strings, byte strings, and dates. If you do not set it, it will get a (hopefully different) random value each time you run `Python`.  Hence `hash('abc')` will give you a consistent value within a single Python execution, but is likely to give you a different value if you restart Python.

You are creating a set of strings. Sets have no guaranteed order, and their internal implementation depends heavily on hash values.

Comment: "You are creating a *set* of strings." That's the essence of it :)

Comment: @bers.  I think you misunderstood my point.  In Java, for example, if I run the same JavaVM twice on the same machine and execute code that creates and prints a set of strings, I'll  likely get the identical output each time, even though the order of a set is not specified.  It's not specified, but it's repeatable.  Python purposely breaks that and says that it's not even repeatable.

Comment: I fully understand that point about sets being non-ordered in Python. My question is not about sets, however. I meant to create a dictionary but didn't - that's the main issue. I should have noticed that elsewhere in my code, but stumbled first across the issue that it's not ordered. So my question is about dicts but the code is not, which is why I closed the question.